# React Router need help routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a beginner front-end dev and I try to make an imaginary website. I'm learning to react router now. So when I try to click on the home/about or contact button, It doesn't open it. What am I doing wrong?

here's my code below :

my App code :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navibar from './Components/Navibar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import About from './Components/About';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';


let App = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navibar/>
      <div className="content">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
          <Home/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/About">
          <About/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="Contact">
          <Contact/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here's my navbar code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Nav, Navbar, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

let Navibar = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">My Portfolio</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="#about">About me</Link>
            <Link to="#contact">Contact</Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navibar;
```

and here's my Home (the home/about and contact codes are the same) code :

```
import React from 'react';


let Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I need help from a professional, because I'm getting stuck in this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Navibar` should link to the route paths you are rendering, not anchor tags (hashes) on the current page. The bootstrap `Navbar.Brand` component should also render a RRD `Link` component instead of a plain anchor tag with href attribute.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navibar = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand
            as={Link} // <-- as a RRD Link component
            to="/"    // <-- to prop for Link component
          >
            My Portfolio
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>           // <-- "/"
            <Link to="/about">About me</Link>  // <-- "/about"
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link> // <-- "/contact"
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navibar;
```

The `App` component should specify route paths that match what the navbar is linking to.

Also the routes `App` is rendering within the `Switch` component should be rendered in inverse order of route path specificity. In other words, render the ***more*** specific paths prior to the ***less*** specific paths. This is to attempt to match and render more specific paths and falling back to less specific paths. This also effectively eliminates the need to use the `exact` prop.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navibar />
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/contact">
              <Contact />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```